# Server side code against <input type="number">

Tags: c#, html

Can someone please tell me how to access control  from server side and set it's property to enabled?

Comment: Can you please first specify what you are using server side to render controls? (MVC, WebForms, something else)

Comment: What technology are you using?  Is this in ASP.NET MVC?  If so, you couldn't access it "server side".  You'd have to pass it along

Comment: Hello David, could you please clarify what you meant by "You'd have to pass it along"

Answer (score 2):

if you are using webforms you need to add `<input type="number" id="numb" runat="server">` specifically add `runat="server"`

and the do this on server side

```
numb.Enabled=false;
```

Comment: Hi. I am using c# in sitefinity platform. So placing Runat-"server" and trying to access iut directly from server side won't help. We have to declare the control like for ex:  public TextBox txtDailyEvery
        {
            get { return this.Container.GetControl<TextBox>("txtDailyEvery", true); }
        }
I am not knowing what type is this <input tyoe="number"/>. I tried almost all controls that might seem working but none of them worked.